# How to fix erasing fields when navigating between forms?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I can't figure out why my field values of User class is disappearing when I'm trying to navigate between forms.

```
@Controller
public class WizardController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        return "form/userForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processedForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result,
                                ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "form/userForm";
        }
        ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
        p.add("add_user");
        p.add("delete_user");
        model.addAttribute("permissions", p);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "form/permissionForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String show(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            return "show";
        } else {
            System.out.println(user);
            return "show";
        }
    }
}
```

My permissionForm.jsp

```
<form:form action="/show" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
    <p>
        <form:select path="permissions">
            <form:options items="${permissions}"/>
        </form:select>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add"/></p>
</form:form>
```

userForm.jsp

```
<form:form action="/user" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
    <p><form:input path="name" placeholder="Name"/></p>
    <p><form:input path="age" placeholder="Age"/></p>
    <p><form:input path="email" placeholder="Email"/></p>
    <p><form:input path="password" placeholder="Password"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form:form>
```

On show.jsp I'm rendering my user

```
${user}
```

And POJO class

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Integer age;
    private List<String> permissions;
    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Output: User{name='null', email='null', password='null', age=null, permissions=[delete_user]}. And I need a full object, somthing like this:

User{name='John', email='john@gmail.com', password='12345', age=21, permissions=[delete_user]}.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you looked into sprint web-flow? http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in permissionForm.jsp, the form has inputs for the permissions field only, hence when submiting it, it will pass on a User object with the permissions  field only populated, the rest will be null.
If you need to have values in the rest of the fields, add hidden inputs like this:

```
<form:form action="/show" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
   <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
   <p>
       <form:select path="permissions">
           <form:options items="${permissions}"/>
       </form:select>
       <form:hidden path="name"/>
       <form:hidden path="age"/>
       <form:hidden path="email"/>
   </p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Add"/></p>
</form:form>
```

However, for the password field, I wouldn't advise adding a hidden field in the JSP because it will expose the password for anyone who can read html source.

Another and better solution would be using the session, by storing and modifying the user in the session between forms, first store the user on the first submit:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processedForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result,
                            ModelMap model,HttpSession session) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "form/userForm";
    }
    session.setAttribute("user",user);
    ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
    p.add("add_user");
    p.add("delete_user");
    model.addAttribute("permissions", p);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "form/permissionForm";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String show(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result,HttpSession session) {
    User userInSession = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
    userInSession.setPermissions(user.getPermissions());

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return "show";
    } else {
        System.out.println(userInSession);
        return "show";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Its nice solution. Thanx. But is there any other solution without 'hidden params'?

Comment: Yes, on first form submit, you can store the user object in the session, and then in the other submits, you can modify the user in the session with the new values you got from submitting the form.

Comment: I'm adding it to the anser

Comment: If you want to store the data of a bean in the session you don't need to fall back the way to `HttpSession`. Check out [@SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-sessionattrib), as well as [Session Scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-session) and [Custom Scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-custom) beans.